# Can i use sqlserver in django 1.6 and python3

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x

I have installed `django-sqlserver (0.5)` with `pip`. In the docs says that engine must be `sqlserver_ado` but it does not work, this is the output `Error was: No module named sqlserver_ado`

This is my settings file:

```
options = {'use_mars': True,
           'allow_nulls_in_unique_constraints': False,  # sqlserver doesn't fully support multiple nulls in unique constraint
           'extra_params': 'DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;',
           'use_legacy_date_fields': False,
           }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'ip',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'OPTIONS': options,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `django-mssql` which is imported using `import sqlserver_ado`

**The relevant info from the django-mssql docs**:

*Although the project is named django-mssql the python module is named sqlserver_ado*

**Python**
 *This backend requires Python 2.6 or newer. Python 3.x support will be investigated when Django supports it.*

The [django packages page](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-mssql/) shows no support for  python 3